# Accessing a composite using E4

Tags: eclipse, e4

In my RCP application, I have a '`Part`' which has 2 composites(`leftComposite` & `rightComposite` which are tied to `parentComposite`). Once the user clicks on the menu, i'm trying to access one of the composites(through `handler/command`) and make it invisible.

How do I access the composite, which belong to a specific `Part`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current `MPart` by injecting it in the handler. From the MPart you get you class for the part using `MPart.getObject()`. To actually deal with the Composites in the part you will have to write code in your class to remember the composites and do what you want.

So the handler would look something like:

```java
@Execute
void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart part)
{
   MyClass myClass = (MyClass)part.getObject();

   // Call code in `MyClass` to do what you want  
}
```

Comment: And again, thats a perfect solution. I don't know how i missed out getObject() method.